# What is the difference between time.perf_counter() and time.process_time()?

Tags: python, time

I am using Jupyter notebook. I'm trying to measure how long will it take to count the Avogadro's number with Python.

I found that `time.perf_counter()` and `time.process_time()` modules will be useful for this kind of work. So I tried both of them, but the result was totally different. What makes this kind of difference?

---

Here is my code.

#### Using `time.perf_counter()`

```
import time

a = 10 ** 5

def AvogadroCounting():
    i = 0
    while i <= a:
        i += 1
        
AvogadroCounting()

t_fract = time.perf_counter()  #time to count fraction of avogadro's number in Seconds


print(t_fract, 'secs')
```

And my notebook gives 693920.393636181 secs.

#### Using time.process_time()

```
import time

a = 10 ** 5

def AvogadroCounting():
    i = 0
    while i <= a:
        i += 1
        
AvogadroCounting()

t_fract =  time.process_time()  #time to count fraction of avogadro's number in Seconds


print(t_fract, 'secs')
```

and this gives 2048.768273 secs.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**`time.perf_counter()` keeps going during sleep, `time.process_time()` does not.**

#### time.perf_counter() → float

Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It **does include time elapsed during sleep** and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

#### time.process_time() → float

Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and user CPU time of the current process. It **does not include time elapsed during sleep**. It is process-wide by definition. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time)

```
import time

def pc():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.perf_counter()-start)

def pt():
    start = time.process_time()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.process_time()-start)

pc()  # 0.99872320449432
pt()  # 0.0
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually read the documents before questioning, but I couldn't know the exact difference between those two modules. Maybe I'm not sure with the meaning of 'sleep'...

Comment: What about the `monotonic`(`_ns`)`()` functions? Are these just low-resolution variants of `perf_counter`(`_ns`)`()`?

Answer (score 82):

`perf_counter()` should measure the *real amount of time* for a process to take, as if you used a stop watch.

`process_time()` will give you the time spent by the computer for the current process, a computer with an OS usually won’t spend 100% of the time on any given process. This counter shouldn’t count the time the CPU is running anything else.

Most cases `perf_counter()` is probably preferable, but `process_time()` can be useful if you want to compare *code efficiency*.

Comment: While that is a nice piece of advice in general, in this case I think the answer is substantially better than the accepted one. Its metaphor of stopwatch and single-tasked computer is really helpful.